# How to fix show method in FragmentDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I write this code to show time in my project when I run the app stop working. However, when I delete show method program works without anything shown when I press the Button

any help please

this is the code

```
public class AlarmFragment extends Fragment implements 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
    private Button clockBtn;
    private TextView time;
 public AlarmFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
    time = view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_time);
    clockBtn= view.findViewById(R.id.clock_btn);
    clockBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment clock= new TimeClock();
              ///////////show method /////////
             clock.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");


        }
    });
    return view;
}
  @Override
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        time.setText("Time:" + hourOfDay +" : "+minute);
      }}
```

this is TimeClock Fragment

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimeClock extends DialogFragment {
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Edit:- so I changed the return statement above, then it works.But onTimeSet method in AlarmFragment did not executed 
 I did it as follow:-

```
Activity activity = new AlarmFragment().getActivity();

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)activity, hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: @pdegand59 I edited my question

Comment: instead of (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity() when you return from TimeClock, you need to pass your TimePickerDialog listener

Comment: @NikosHidalgo you are right,I did that then it works, but on onTimeSet method did not work time textView didn`t change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Activity` that hosts your `AlarmFragment`, you must implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`.

For example:

```
public class MainActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "chosen hour of day: " + hourOfDay, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. Maybe you imported the wrong class? The stacktrace is very specific: `com.example.mypc.bookorganizer.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener`... if you implemented it this would not happen.

Comment: import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.TimePicker;   //////these are the class are imported in AlarmFragment

Comment: My answer says, and the stacktrace also clearly says, that your **activity** (`com.example.mypc.bookorganizer.MainActivity`) must implement the interface, not your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `ClassCastException` because your `getActivity` is not a `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`, but your `AlarmFragment` is:

```
// this is where it fails, change this line, do not copy
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

You can refactor your `TimeClock` class to delegate the listener:

```
public class TimeClock extends DialogFragment {

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener;

    public void setOnTimeSetListener(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        // Now delegates the listener to the constructor
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

And set your listener before `TimeClock.show`:

```
DialogFragment clock= new TimeClock();
clock.setOnTimeSetListener(this);
clock.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
```

Comment: I got an error (cannot resolve setOnTimeSetListener method )

Comment: Because you haven't written it..?

Comment: I Wrote it just as you did but still have the same problem

Comment: @Shaima I don't know what you did, as long as your `TimePickerDialog` second argument is not an activity type then it should work.

Comment: I change it to activity and I declare it Activity activity = new AlarmFragment().getActivity(); the program works but onTimeSet method in AlarmFragment did not executed

Comment: Why would you do `Activity activity = new AlarmFragment().getActivity();`? The `activity` will surely be null. Also can you double check the answer again? You should be returning `return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));`. The second argument is `listener`, not `getActivity()`.

Comment: I copy what you wrote as it is but still have the same problem

Comment: @Shaima Did you copy the first line of code? I was pointing out your mistake.. do not use that line..?

Comment: No I did not writ the first line, I just understand it as you update it . It works when I implement   TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener in MainActivity. Thank you very much =)